# Can RMongo connect to MongoDB cloud?

Tags: r, mongodb

I have made a couple attempts to connect but no joy:

```
> rmng <-  mongoDbConnect('test', 'mongodb+srv://myuser:mypassword@cluster1-234nq.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
Error in .jnew("rmongo/RMongo", dbName, host, as.integer(port)) : 
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "//myuser"


> rmng <-  mongoDbConnect('test', host='cluster1-234nq.mongodb.net')
Error in .jnew("rmongo/RMongo", dbName, host, as.integer(port)) : 
  java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster1-234nq.mongodb.net


> rmng <-  mongoDbConnect('test', 'myuser@cluster1-234nq.mongodb.net')
Error in .jnew("rmongo/RMongo", dbName, host, as.integer(port)) : 
  java.net.UnknownHostException: myuser@cluster1-234nq.mongodb.net
> rmng <-  mongoDbConnect('test', 'cluster1-234nq.mongodb.net')
Error in .jnew("rmongo/RMongo", dbName, host, as.integer(port)) : 
  java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster1-234nq.mongodb.net
```

The main error I keep getting is the unknowhost exception as above. The first line i tried has the connect string provided by MongoDB Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMongo is using a very old MongoDB driver and it has not been actively maintained since 2015 (according to the [RMongo GitHub repo commits](https://github.com/tc/RMongo)).

It definitely predates [`mongodb+srv` connection string support](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-3-6-here-to-SRV-you-with-easier-replica-set-connections) and all modern versions of MongoDB (since the last update was prior to MongoDB 3.2 being released). The RMongo package has been [removed from CRAN (The Comprehensive R Archive Network repository)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMongo/index.html) as it no longer supports any current versions of MongoDB.

I would recommend looking into [`mongolite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/), which is actively maintained and will definitely work with modern versions of the MongoDB server & MongoDB Atlas.